# Asp.Net MVC - Automatically Login with External Login Each Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm using the MVC template in Visual Studio 2015 and I've setup Facebook authentication.  If the user has previously logged in to the site, the next time they return, I would like them to be automatically logged in again.  I changed "isPersistent" to "true" in ExternalLoginCallback/AccountController and that seems to do the trick.  Is that it?  Are there any other options, like how long to remember the user or any other spots where this needs to be changed?

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        } 

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: true);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```